# Storing a multiple select in a database for a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, controller, html-select

I have a model for "Location" which has a title, description, and type. The type can be a "Bar", "Restaurant", etc. I want to have a select box in my view with the various options with multiple selections available.

How would i go about parsing the select box in my controller and storing it in the database?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to use type as select box in a Location form,  you could put the possible types inside the Location class.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :type
  TYPES = ["Bar", "Restaurant"]
end
```

View

```
<%= f.select(:type, options_for_select(Location::TYPES.each {|y| y.capitalize! } ), { :prompt => "Select Type" }) %>
```

Comment: How would i use this with multiple selects allowed? What sort of database field would I need?

Comment: What you mean by multiple selects ?  Like you select the type from a sub select ?

Comment: The form object <select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select> etc., where they can select multiple options at once

Comment: So a Location can be of multiple types ?  You will need a LocationType class, and to create a many to many relationship to this class, using has_and_belongs_to_many or has_many :through.  Then you could loop through the incoming types of your form and assign to the location